# Partial View does not show when passed a parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view for a create function that uses a dialog box and pops up whenever i click a specific button within the index page (the controllers for the index and create page are different). Whenever I try to pass a parameter from the index to the create and click the button to show the dialog box, it doesn't show the partial view. But when I remove the parameter, the dialog box shows the partial view though the post action for it won't work since I need the parameter from the index page.

Here is the lines from the index that passes the parameter and the button used to be clicked for the dialog box to appear:

```
<input type="button" class="btnPartial" />
                    <div id="@item.RoomCode" style ="visibility:hidden;">@Url.Action("CallPartial", "RoomReservation", new { roomId = item.Id })</div>                  
                </div>
```

Here is the controller that receives the parameter from the index page and shows the partial view:

```
 public ActionResult CallPartial(int roomId) {
            var model = _db.Rooms.Single(r => r.Id == roomId);
            ViewBag.roomCode = model.RoomCode;
            return PartialView("_Create", model.Customers );
        }
```

Here is the Partial View:

```
@model ROOMRESERVATION.CORE.Model.RoomReservation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h3>@ViewBag.roomCode</h3>
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rooms.RoomName)
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RoomReservation", new {roomid = model.Rooms.Id}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
     <legend>RoomReservation</legend>
@Html.Partial("_CreateEdit", Model)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remarks)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks)
</div>
<p>
    <input id="btnReserve" type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Lastly, the JS:

```
$('.btnPartial').click(function () {

        var url = $(this).parent("div").children("div").text();

        $('#dialog').load(url,
                function (response, status, xhr) {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                });

        $("body").toggleClass("dialogIsOpen");

        $("#dialogContainer").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
```

The models for it are ALL OK since other controllers and Views respond to it and when i was still using the the view for create, the parameter thing works and the program runs smoothly so I have a hunch that the problem is within the usage of the partial view and the dialog box.  Any help will be appreciated, Thanks :)

**EDIT**

I tried using the the viewdata to pass to the partial view and it worked, but It seems a weird thing to do so if there are more ways of doing so, please post any method :).

Comment: Did you checked the generated HTML? Did you checked the data from the response? Please use Firebug or Chrome to find JS erros, look for the response and post here!

Comment: There are no errors when it comes to JS, but it shows this error instead Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). And I whenever i tried doing it w/o the parameters, no errors occur and it goes smoothly until  before the post action initialtes

Comment: Well, decorate the action method with [HttpGet]! Thats the deal :)!

Comment: Still, it didn't work :(

Comment: Hmm silly! Could you show the url?

Comment: BUT! I tried something and it worked! I used a ViewData within the controller to pass it to the partial view, then used is for another parameter for the post action, and voila a record was born!

Comment: Try to rewrite the load with $.ajax, this is silly, i did this several times and no issues! Well done then! But give the rewrite try!

Comment: Url of the page for the create page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30098/discussion-between-fals-and-lou-lising)

Comment: I'm still a newbie to this so I'll try using the ajax method but I haven't used it before so I will be needing a bit of reading for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
 $('.btnPartial').click(function () {
    $(this).preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).parent("div").children("div").text();
    var dialogWindow = $('#dialog');
    var opt = {
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto'
    }

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        //
        // Loads the data into the div
        //
        $(dialogWindow).html(data);
    }).done(function () {
        //
        // Show the Dialog when all data comes from the server
        //
        $(dialogWindow).dialog(opt).dialog('open');
    });

    $("body").toggleClass("dialogIsOpen");

    $("#dialogContainer").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Hopes this help you!

Comment: It has the same error as the last one where when w/ parameters the dialog doesn't show but w/o it will run.

Comment: OMG I wanna solvc this!! Could you give me the url used?

Comment: What url are you looking for? for the create form?

Comment: From this @Url.Action("CallPartial", "RoomReservation", new { roomId = item.Id }

Comment: /RoomReservation/CallPartial?roomId=1 (the roomId changes depending on what button you clicked so the value depends on how many rooms i have created)

Answer (score 0):

I just think because your dialog could not display because the AJAX calling. So why don't you think that we can use AJAX calling and put the partial to one HTML element like div, and after finished we will append that element into the dialog.